# how to prevent textEdit in pyqt from changing

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit

how to prevent textEdit in pyqt from changing when to many characters are entered?
can not find setting qt designer to limit number of characters, or limit auto resizing of box.
tried:

```
self.ui.textEdit_45.setFixedSize(30,  30)
```

set the minimium and maximium to width 30, height 30
sizePolicy [Fixed, Fixed, 0, 0]
did not work

if more than 2 characters are entered, the box gets 2 x's at top right and bottom left, and can not make out what is in the box.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing"? For me, the default text-edit does not resize in any way when entering text. It automatically word-wraps and uses a vertical scroll-bar whenever necessary. What do you mean by "2 x's"? I cannot see how to reproduce any of this behaviour. Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: the automatically word-wraps and uses a vertical scroll-bar is in a 30 x 30 area

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot make any sense out of what you are saying. Can you provide some screenshots to show what you mean? Are you just trying to stop word-wrapping and scrolling?

Comment: my ranking does not allow for screen shots. guessing it is called word-wrapping and scrolling

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to count the character the textEdit has `QTextEdit.toPlainText()` every time the text changes `self.textEdit.textChanged.connect()`. If the number of character makes the QTextEdit deforme, make appear like the input it's disabled by slicing the input.

MWE:

```
from PyQt4 import  QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    TwoDigits = 2 # Maximum number of characters allowed

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        #define QTextEdit
        self.TE = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.TE.setGeometry(0,0, 30,30)

        self.TE.textChanged.connect(self.Limiter)

    def Limiter(self):
        NumChar = len( self.TE.toPlainText() )
        # according to geometry 2 characters is enough, so enter if over TwoDigits
        if NumChar > self.TwoDigits:
            Text = self.TE.toPlainText() # get text
            Text = Text[:self.TwoDigits] # slice first TwoDigits
            print(Text) # debugging
            self.TE.setPlainText(Text) # set sliced text
            self.TE.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End) # move cursor to end, like if nothing happens

app = QtGui.QApplication([sys.argv])
win = MWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: that would prevent text from being entered, not prevent box change

Comment: during my research, I coudn't find a way to prevent box change under your conditions. But my edited answear has a workaround to deal with maximum number of characters (given by you) avoiding the need to force the box size.